# Leveraging Powerful Code Snippets and How to Separate Style sheets?

Tags: html, css, django, stylesheet, code-snippets

I'm not the best at creating beautiful web pages from scratch and forms are ugly, if made by me. There are a ton of beautiful CSS code snippet solutions out there and they are awesome. I'm currently learning python-django and I'm trying to use a bunch of code snippets but since I'm new at this, I don't know how to separate the css/style.css sheets that come with each separate snippet. Is there a way to isolate each style sheet to be used for only a specific snippet? If I load all of these style sheets in my header, some get overridden because they all have a different style for, say, a paragraph or body etc...

this is my file structure:

```
src/
  djangoTest/
    djangoTest/
      __init__.py
      settings.py
      urls.py
      ...
    djangoTestApp/
      models/
        __init__.py
        modelsUser.py
        ...
      static/
        css/
        images/
        javascript/
      tests.py
      views.py
      __init__.py
    templates/
      index.html
  manage.py
```

What I want to do is put the different css style sheets (from the code snippets) into a different folder and link only those snippets to their respective style sheets. Right now I just link all of the css style sheets and they overlap which makes it hard for me to separate the code snippets.

example file structure:

```
static/
  css/snippet1_css/style.css
  css/snippet2_css/style.css
  ...
```

Then for each html snippet, only use the css for it's respective stylesheet. This may be a dumb question but I haven't figured out the answer yet.

Here's an example of what I want to do. I really like this form: http://www.webdezign.co.uk/html5-examples/sexy-form/
and I've placed it in one of my views. I also really like this search bar:
http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/search-dropdown/demo

So how do I put both code snippets into one view without overlapping css/style.css?
This would be so cool if I could figure this out. I would really appreciate the help here!
Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think should be a better solution:

In views.py

```
Class FirstView(TemplateView)
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FirstView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['css_snipped_path'] = 'css/snippet1_css/style.css'
        return context

Class SecondView(TemplateView)
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SecondView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['css_snipped_path'] = 'css/snippet2_css/style.css'
        return context
```

Then in your template (like index.html)

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ css_snipped_path }}">
</head>
```

Comment: That's a cool solution but what if I wanted multiple snippets in a same view? Is it possible, to then assign certain snippets to use a specific css stylesheet?

Comment: For example, when I add stylesheets into my app, my footer gets affected by the styling when I don't want it to.

Comment: I think that is a css problem? i'm not css expert. or i disnt understant you :)